# Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

There is a way to make TOC using `\tableofcontents`, but there are only sections and subsections.

How can I get list of all frames without using sectioning?

Comment: Welcome! What do you want to have as content? Only the frame numbers?

Comment: No, frame numbers and titles.

Comment: Or simple itemized list. I guess I can write shell script but wonder if it can be done by latex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using the `\@starttoc` command through the newly defined \listofframes command; the new list will have extension `.lbf`. `\addtobeamertemplate` was used so that the `frametitle` command writes the desired information (frame number and title) to the `.lbf` file. The list is created issuing `\listofframes`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the resulting List of Frames:

[image]

To facilitate control over which frames to include in the new list, you can use a boolean switch; in the following example I used `\ifframeinlbf` initially set to true; if you want to suppress some titled frame(s) from the list of frames, use `\frameinlbffalse` right before those frame(s) and then use `\frameinlbftrue` right after the frame(s) to activate inclusion in the list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\par}%
  \else\fi
}

\begin{document}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that faded tick on the left is hard to find first time.

Done.

Thank you

Comment: Now I have homework - remove from TOC contents slide itself :)

Comment: @kryksyh please see my updated answer.

Comment: May be I am doing something wrong, but `\frameinlbftrue` doesn't turn frameinlbf to true when placed inside {document}

Comment: @kryksyh: of course it does; my example code illustrates this, so perhaps there's something else going on in your code... Two possible causes: 1) You need to process your document at least two times, or 2) Perhaps you are using `\frameinlbftrue`  inside a `frame` environment? (it must go outside the frame environment) If this is not the problem, I will need to see some code showing the undesired behaviour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3492/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-kryksyh)

Comment: The problem was in `ignorenonframetext` option in `\documentclass`. All non-frame text including `\frameinlbftrue` was skipping.

Comment: Is it possible to have this solution work if I have a latex tag such as \emph{} inside a frame title? It says something about an invalid \end{frame} tag at the end of the first frame which has such a tag in the \frametitle{}. Thanks.

Comment: @SandroGržičić please feel free to open a follow up question, and add there a minimal example document (like the one in my example code) allowing us to reproduce the mentioned problem.

Comment: I did, here's the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125540/how-to-produce-a-list-of-frames-with-beamer-if-frame-titles-have-latex-tags-in-t

Comment: Great stuff. However, this solution seems to have troubles with the `allowframebreaks` option. I get a "TeX capacity exceeded" error, supposedly because of the internal handling of automatic frame breaks in the beamer code. Thx for a comment on your original solution.

Comment: This solution appears to fail when the allowframebreaks option is used.

Comment: @Mario @Dan Fox I managed to make this to work with `allowframebreaks` by making `usebeamertemplate` robust. Add this to the preamble:  

`usepackage{makerobust}`  
`\MakeRobustCommand\usebeamertemplate`

Comment: Thanks, @jorpppp, I will try that.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Your answer recently stopped working. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631271/36835) provides the fix.

Comment: I implemented your listofframes, but the compiler does not seem to like the space factor. I get, in the .log file [. {/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.344 \end{frame}
                 
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Gonzalo Medina's answer, if you want frame titles to link to page numbers, use this code just before the `\insertframetitle`:

```
\protect\hyperlink{page.\insertframenumber}
```

So the full code is:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \protect\hyperlink{page.\insertframenumber}\insertframetitle\par}%
  \else\fi
}
```

The above requires the `hyperref` package, so make sure you include it.

Answer (score 4):

The [**answer of Sandro**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125544/36835) shows a very useful addition to [**Gonzalo Medinas answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56541/36835) in case one actually wants to use the list of frames as a link collection to easy access a certain frame.

However, the solution of Sandro fails if one resets the frame counter during the presentation. This is a more robust approach which also consideres overlays to avoid multiple links of the same frame:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \only<1>{%
      \hypertarget{\insertframetitle}{}%
      \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
      \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
      \protect\hyperlink{\insertframetitle}{\insertframetitle}\par}% 
    }%
}
```

Comment: Works great unless I put ${\mathbb {R}}$ inside a framework title, in which case there is the 'undefined controlled sequence' error - any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev have you tried the the optional argument `\frametitle[linktitle]{${\mathbb {R}}$}`?

Comment: No luck, the same annoying error as soon as \mathbb is present, linking to the entry 
`\contentsline {section}{\makebox [2em][l]{\usebeamercolor [fg]{structure}5\hfill }\hyperlink {{${\mathbb {R}}$}}{{${\mathbb {R}}$}}\par }` inside the *.lbf file.

Answer (score 3):

i want to add some comments to the solution of Sandro:

The code was not working for me until i changed the line

```
 \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
```

to

```
\addcontentsline{lbf\thesection}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
```

Further, the idea with the link is good, but if you have uncover-effects, e.g. with pause, uncover, ..., the framenumber does not correspond with the page number. Thus i changed the line

```
\protect\hyperlink{page.\insertframenumber}\insertframetitle\par}%
```

to

```
\protect\hyperlink{page.\insertpagenumber}\insertframetitle\par}%
```

Hope i was able to contriubte something!

Comment: is it possible to make the list arranged alphabetically?