# Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section / part

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

With reference to [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer)

how can this be done so as to only list the frames contained within a section in the title slide for that section, assuming a multi section/part presentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's ome possible solution generating a list of all frames used in a section, on a per section basis; here I used a simple modification of the answer you linked to; the boolean `\ifframeinlbf` allows to include (if true) or to exclude (if false) specific frames in the corresponding list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\vfill\@starttoc{lbf\thesection}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf\thesection}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\vfill}%
  \else\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section One}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One Two}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section Two}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Two}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Three}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the frames showing the lists of frames for each section:

[image]

[image]

One thing that can be improved is that this solution uses an auxiliary file for each section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works as you have demonstrated. However, if I were to add an [allowframebreaks] tag to any frame that is to be listed in the lbf file (e.g any of the Test Frames), it would result in an error - "Argument of \beamer@usebeamertemplatedosss has an extra }". Assuming the [allowframebreaks] is necessary, can the solution be modified to work with it ?