# Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section / part with the use of [allowframebreaks]

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

Please see [Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section / part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56992/beamer-presentation-list-of-frames-within-a-section-part). I have copy-pasted Gonzalo Medina's example code below. Uncommenting the [allowframebreaks] or using it in any other frame that is also to be listed in the lbf file results in an error. Is there a way of obtaining the same result WITH the use of [allowframebreaks], assuming the context requires its use ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\vfill\@starttoc{lbf\thesection}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf\thesection}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\vfill}%
  \else\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section One}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Test Frame One One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One Two}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section Two}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Two}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Three}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: MWE]

With a more *conventional* approach, that is, making a subsection for each frame and touching beamer options, it is possible obtain a TOC with only the actual section highlighted and showing only the list of frames (=subsections) of that section.

Is a different display but hopefully make the same function (?) and the simpler code work without problems with  `allowframebreaks`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}

%macros only to simplify commands in document  
\newcommand\newframeb[1]{%
\subsection[]{#1}\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{#1}}

\newcommand\newframe[1]{%
\subsection[]{#1}\begin{frame}{#1}}

\begin{document}

% This make the partial TOCs
\AtBeginSection[]
{\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}}

\section{Test Section One}
\newframe{Test Frame One One} Single frame \end{frame}
\newframeb{Test Frame One Two (breaked)}
Break  \vspace{3 cm} \\ frame \vspace{3 cm} \\
Break  \vspace{3 cm} \\ frame \vspace{3 cm} \\
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\newframe{Test Frame Two One} test \end{frame}
\newframeb{Test Frame Two Two (breaked)} 
Break  \vspace{3 cm} \\ frame \vspace{3 cm} \\
Break  \vspace{3 cm} \\ frame \vspace{3 cm} \\
\end{frame}
\newframe{Test Frame Two Three} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the changes `beamer` makes to `\insertframetitle` (to add a `\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}` wrapped in a conditional) when the option `allowframebreaks` is used.

There are a couple of issues with this:

1. `\usebeamertemplate` is not safe in an expansion-only context, as it looks for `*`s
2. `\usebeamertemplate*` executes `\usebeamercolor` which is expanded at the wrong time

Here's a local fix that goes straight to the result of the `*`-parsing, and `\protect`s the `\usebeamercolor` etc:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\vfill\@starttoc{lbf\thesection}}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \bgroup
  \patchcmd\insertframetitle{\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}}{{{\protect\usebeamerfont{frametitle continuation}\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle continuation}\beamer@usebeamertemplatedo{frametitle continuation}}}}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
  \addcontentsline{lbf\thesection}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \insertframetitle\vfill}%
  \egroup
  \else\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section One}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Test Frame One One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One Two}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames for Section Two}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Two}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two Three}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to remove the continuation counter completely from the list of frames, instead of patching `\insertframetitle`, one could just do `\beamer@autobreakcount=0` in its place (on the same line so again the change remains local).