# beamer: table of frames

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm looking for a possibility to create a table of frames. The MWE illustrate my question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}{Topic 1}
Some stuff
\end{frame}
\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}{Topic 2}
Other stuff
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Without the `\section` entries, the toc will be empty. Is there a way, to include all frametitles automatically to the toc or a similiar list?

Comment: You could redefine `\frame` to that it be preceded by some sectioning command...

Comment: Do you mean a list of frames like [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56512/13304) or [Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section / part](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56992/13304)?