# Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section which produces double numbering

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

when I compiled the example given in an answer to post ["Beamer presentation: List of frames within a section / part"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56992/beamer-presentation-list-of-frames-within-a-section-part), I end up with 
double numbering (with a shift) for frames except for the first one in the section.  Like [image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://kde35.free.fr/files/tocerror.png))</sub>

[image: this.]

Is there anything wrong with my beamer installation?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I just tried the example by Gonzalo Medina and I can't reproduce your issue. Did you use the example without changes?

Comment: No changes, I copy-pasted his code.

Comment: Well, I did the same. Is your `beamer` installation up - to -date? I've used the TL 2015 (latest state before being frozen) on Linux

Comment: It comes from kubuntu latex-beamer package 3.07-1, which is quite old, so probably it is where the problem comes from.  I will try to update  beamer and see if it solves the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Current version seem to be 3.36, so `3.07-1` seems to be a little bit aged ;-)

Comment: The source compiled correctly on another machine using mint latex-beamer 3.10.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a major change between 3.07 and 3.10 -- I can't check this, however, without much efforts (installing old versions requires a separate TL tree)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to an out-dated beamer installation