# How to produce a list of frames with Beamer if frame titles have LaTeX tags in them?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, errors

Related to: [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer)

The above method works if frame titles don't have tags such as `\emph{}` in them. However, if a frame title has such a tag, the error message is :

```
"Undefined control sequence: \end{frame}"
```

How can this be fixed?

Here's a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
   \insertframetitle\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
% error location 
\frametitle{\emph{emph in frametitle}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to `\protect` the emphasized title, thus use `\frametitle{\protect\emph{emph in frametitle}}`.

Comment: That works, thanks! You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the reason why the use of `\emph` causes an error, please refer to [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands).

The solution is to `\protect` the emphasized title, thus use `\frametitle{\protect\emph{emph in frametitle}}`.

The working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme{tree}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
   \insertframetitle\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{\protect\emph{emph in frametitle}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]