# Examining the current value of a beamertemplate

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

Beamer offers `\setbeamertemplate` and `\addtobeamertemplate`. I am trying to change one of these templates, but I cannot find a command to examine the current value of a template.

The use case is that I try to add the from number to the frame title in `article` mode. I would like to make other modification to the default rendering of frames, and this some rather difficult without knowing the default behavior of frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\setbeamertemplate{<element>}{<template>}` creates `\csname beamer@@tmpl@<element>\endcsname` to be `<template>` (in [`beamertemplates.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasetemplates.sty)). So, you could examine

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\show\csname beamer@@tmpl@<element>\endcsname
\makeatother
```

`\addtobeamertemplate` adds content to the same `\beamer@@tmpl@<element>`.