# How to extract a list of all frame titles in beamer?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

This may sound similar to [other questions on generating a "list of frames"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125540/30658) but my goal is different: While these question try to generate a "list of frames" within the presentation itself, I only want to extract the list for external use. In particular, I want to prepare a small print-out for myself, maybe looking like this:

```
01 <no title>
02 Introduction
03 Introduction
04 Open Issues
...
```

The important thing for me would be to know which PDF page number corresponds to which slide title. My use case: I want to prepare a large number of backup slides. During Q&A such a list would allow me to look up certain slides and quickly jump to the corresponding page number. Is there a simple way to generate such a list? (raw text would be sufficient)

Comment: Why not just use the method in your linked question and make the list the last slide?  Then print it out if you need to.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Including the backup slides, I have ~100 slides, so I would prefer an external solution to format the list more efficiently. Apart from that it would be useful to create an [impressive script](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You could also use `\addtobeamertemplate` like in the linked question and instead of using it to write a content line, write the output you like [into a file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2115412).

Comment: @Benjamin: It is not that easy, because I couldn't find a way to write out on every slide, only on those which have a frametitle. So it will only work if all slides have a title.

Comment: You could use `etoolbox`s  `\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{...}` as a hook to also write out the slides without title.

Answer (score 4):

This is only a semi solution, because it will only write those frames into an external file, which have a `frametitle`. If all the slides (except for the title slide) have a title, you can simply add 1 to the slide number to have a PDF page to frametitle mapping. If some slides do not have a title there will however be gaps.

In the preamble I use this:

```
\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=slidelist.txt

\newcounter{SlideNumber}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \stepcounter{SlideNumber}
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\theSlideNumber [\insertframenumber] \insertframetitle}
}
```

At the end of the document the file has to be closed:

```
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
```

This will generate a file `slidelist.txt` looking like this:

```
1[2] {Introduction}
2[2] {Introduction}
3[2] {Introduction}
4[3] {Open Issues}
5[3] {Open Issues}
```

The left number is a simple counter (you can initialize it to 1 to account for the title slide), corresponding to the individual pages that are generated in the PDF. The second number corresponds to the displayed frame number, which takes into account incremental slides.