# Combining Beamer-List-of-frames with TOC (sections etc.)?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, beamerarticle

Related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer) »Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?«

1. Is there a way of combining TOC (`section` / `subsection`) with this listofframes? (e.g. frametitles just like `subsubsection`?
2. Is it possible to combine this also with the `beamerarticle` Package to create a complete table of contents for a lecture manuscript?

The minimal example linked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer) does not allow that, I suppose we need something like:

`\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{title}`

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you get what you want if you change `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%` to `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%` ?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I tried, but didn't work for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure it is a good ides to do this; the ToC might get really crowded with unnecessary information. Anyway, here' one possibility (but I don't know how robust will it be when changing to `article` and using `beamerarticle`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifframeintoc

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\mode<article>
{
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsubsection}{\insertframetitle\hfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\par}
}
\mode<presentation>
{\ifframeintoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsubsection}{%
    \protect\hspace{2em}\footnotesize%
   \protect\hyperlink{page.  \insertframenumber}{\insertframetitle}\par}%
\fi
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\frameintoctrue% activate frame titles in ToC
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Three}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Four}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Five}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Six}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Seven}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Eight}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC in presentation mode (frame titles are hyperlinked to their corresponding frame):

[image]

And now, with the same settings but replacing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
```

the ToC looks like

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, works in beamer- and article-version for me. Thank you!

Comment: This also works for me, after removing the blanks in `page.  \insertframenumber`.