# Call macro after every \section in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, etoolbox

This is a follow-up question of [***Add section titles to list of frames***](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329342/add-section-titles-to-list-of-frames-insertsection-does-not-work/330316).

As you can see in the minimal example below I call the same macro after every `\section` and I'd like to automize it. I basically tried every command provided by **etoolbox** (`\apptocmd`, `\appto`, `\gappto`, `\csappto`, etc.), but got none of them working. Which one is the right one and how should it be used? Or are there other solutions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \mode<presentation>
    {
    \only<1>{
    \hypertarget{\insertframetitle}{}%
          \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
          \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\scriptsize\insertframenumber\hfill}%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
              \scriptsize\protect\hyperlink{\insertframetitle}{\insertframetitle}%
          \else%
              \scriptsize\protect\hyperlink{\insertframetitle}{\insertframesubtitle}%
          \fi%
          \par}%
    }
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sectioninlbf}{
\addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{%
        \vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
        \protect\footnotesize%
        \secname\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}\sectioninlbf

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}\sectioninlbf
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
\framesubtitle{Test Frame Two Subtitle}
test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Three}
\uncover<1->{test}
\uncover<2->{test}
\uncover<3->{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \mode<presentation>
    {
    \only<1>{
    \hypertarget{\insertframetitle}{}%
          \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
          \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\scriptsize\insertframenumber\hfill}%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
              \scriptsize\protect\hyperlink{\insertframetitle}{\insertframetitle}%
          \else%
              \scriptsize\protect\hyperlink{\insertframetitle}{\insertframesubtitle}%
          \fi%
          \par}%
    }
    }
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection{%
\addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{%
        \vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
        \protect\footnotesize%
        \secname\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{General outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Two}
\framesubtitle{Test Frame Two Subtitle}
test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Three}
\uncover<1->{test}
\uncover<2->{test}
\uncover<3->{test}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]