# is it possible to insert frametitles in toc

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to insert frame titles in toc, I make subsection pages named as the following frametitle to make an entry in toc. Is there a way to include frame titles in toc without doing so?

```
    \documentclass[t]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section
{Section 1}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\subsection
{subsection 1 named as frame 1}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame1}
FRAME 1
\end{frame}
\subsection
{subsection 2 named as frame 2}
\frame{\subsectionpage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame2}
FRAME 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125616/121799)?

Comment: I've also found a good answer and very good comments in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer