# Is there a way to remove duplicate frame titles from a listofframes?

Tags: beamer

Related to: [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer)

I have a lot of slides where there are successive identically named slides, for example the first one explains the topic and the second one has an example. 
I'd like that the `\listofframes` only shows the first one.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using multiple frames with the same title? How about using one frame with overlay commands, such as `only<x>`, to keep everything in one frame, and combine that with `\listofframes` as explained in the link you posted?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the overlay commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the answer right in [your linked post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer):

> if you want to suppress some titled frame(s) from the list of frames, use \frameinlbffalse right before those frame(s) and then use \frameinlbftrue right after the frame(s) to activate inclusion in the list:

Comment: Right, but there are dozens of such frames, it's tedious to do them one at a time. I'll fall back to this method only if there's nothing better.

Comment: I'm accepting this since there doesn't seem to be a better way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\only<1> {
  \frametitle{Frame One}
  Some text.
}
\only<2> {
  Some more text.
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Two}
Some text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can insert the `\frametitle{<title>}` directive within `\only<1>` to prevent subsequent slides produced by the `\only<x>` directives from being shown in the table of frames. This, achieves what you wanted at the expense of the title appearing only in the slide produced by the `\only<1>` block.

I'm sure someone can come up with a far superior solution, but if you only need to show the title once, this should suffice.

Comment: Sadly, this solution seems to still generate multiple frame titles. Also, all the multiple frames (obviously) have identical frame numbers, lowering the real frame count.

Comment: Yes, apologies. I couldn't test my answer at all because I was not in front of my PC. I've edited my post with a new answer which prevents duplicate entries in the table of frames, but it comes at the expense of having the frame title show only in the first slide of each frame.

Comment: Ok, but your solution isn't that much better than the "default" one with inserting \frameinlbf boolean tags, and clutters my latex a lot with the \only<>{} directives. Thanks for trying though.