# List of frames, where the frames have overlay

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

## Related question: [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer)

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \ifframeinlbf
    \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][1]{%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
    \insertframetitle\par}%
    \else\fi
}

\begin{document}

\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{List of frames}

\listofframes

\end{frame}

\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{First frame}

\only<1-2>{Água mole em pedra dura \ldots}

\only<2>{\ldots tanto bate até que fura.}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Second frame}

Água mole em pedra dura tanto bate até que fura.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the "List of frames" frame the "First frame" appears twice.
What could I do to make it appear just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, there's already plenty of commands for doing things only on certain overlays. This one will create the entries only for overlay 1:

```
\newcommand\frametocentry{%
    \ifframeinlbf
    \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][1]{%
        \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}%
    \insertframetitle\par}%
    \else\fi
}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \only<1>{\frametocentry}
}
```

Comment: That worked pretty well! Just one thing: I don't need to start my overlays with `\only<2>` because of the `\only<1>`, do I?

Comment: @Larara: no, you just shouldn't have a `\begin{frame}<2->` because that would tell beamer to skip the first frame altogether. (I think.)

Comment: let me tell you just one more thing that I think that's strange: the frametitle is not preceded by the frame number as in the example given in the first answer of that related question above...

Comment: there's something strange, I compiled the .tex again and now it isn't working!