# Is there any way to insert the list of frames in beamer, in the current section, and following the current frame?

Tags: beamer

My question is similar to this one:

[Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer)

but i'm interested to get only the list of frames following the current frame and in the current section.

There is an easy way to adapt that question?

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \only<1>{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{%
         \protect\beamer@subsectionintoc{\the\c@section}{0}{%
             \insertframetitle%
         }{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}{\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[sections=\value{section}]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
Text
\end{frame}



\section{Second Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third frame}
\framesubtitle{mySubtitle}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fourth frame}
Text
\pause
more text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with this. Beamer does not recognise the \insertframetitle command