# Adding a Tikz picture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am a new beamer user and I am not sure what is going wrong when I am trying to add a Tikz picture on a slide of my beamer presentation, it keeps going on a different frame (i.e. slide) than I want it to. How would I fix this issue?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
\section{Section 1} 

\subsection{Description.}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
\newdimen\R \R=1cm

\foreach \i [count=\j] in { 1,2,3,4,5,6}
{
\node (n\j) [dot, label=60*\j:$\i$] at (60*\j:\R) {};
\draw[blue,thick]  (0,0) -- (n\j);
}



{
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
    \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
    \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
}
    \end{tikzpicture}



\section{Section 2} 


\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: If I do `\documentclass{beamer} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} <your code> \end{document}` I get a PDF with two slides, the first one has a table of contents, the second your diagram. Which is exactly what one would expect. What did you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: I want to have the tikz image in the same frame as my text.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `beamer` works. `\section` and `\subsection` are actually supposed to be added *outside* `frame` environments, and they don't add text to the presentation. If you want a title for the frame, use `\frametitle{foo}` after `\begin{frame}`.

Comment: So how would I go about adding text and tikz images in the same frame?

Comment: Just add the text in the frame ... It's just that `\section`/`\subsection` won't be shown in the slides (except for the ToC), but there's nothing stopping you from writing normal text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments?

Comment: Maybe leave open? The question is answered in comments but in a very high-level way, a real answer may be useful.

Answer (score 4):

To help close this question, I put together an MWE to show the differences between sectioning commands (`\section` and `\subsection`) and frame titles.

Also how to make a document, class `article`, (article mode) from a beamer presentation (presentation mode), hiding some frames.

Compiling the code will produce a beamer presentation of 6 frames (F1 to F6): the title (F1), the Overview (F2) showing the structure of sections and subsections using  `\tableofcontents` (but not the list of frames!) and 4 additional frames with content.

The tikz figure is in the frame `F4 Connections` under the subsection `Description`.

The code is in beamer mode. Note that the `\section` and `\subsection` commands are used  outside of the frame environment.

To switch to article mode comment  `\documentclass{beamer}` and uncomment both
`\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`.

Frame #5 was marked as `\mode <presentation>` so it will show in  mode presentation, but not in mode article.

The result is a three-page article: a title page, the table of contents showing sections and subsections with the title used in the `F2 Overview` frame, and pages with the content, where the frame titles appear as `\paragraph` because for each frame issues a `\paragraph*{<frame title>}`.

Frame #5 does not appear under section 2, as expected.

Note that the `\newpage` and `\bigskip` commands, useful in article mode, had no effect in presentation mode.

To produce a list of frames in beamer mode see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56541/161015

**Structure of the presentation**

[image: ex]

**Beamer frame #2 using `\tableofcontents`**

[image: b2]

**Beamer frame #4,  the tikz figure**

[image: b4]

**Article mode, table of contents**

[image: a2]

**Article mode, the contents**

[image: a3]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer} %Un-comment to produce a presentation

%\documentclass{article} %Comment  to produce a presentation
%\usepackage{beamerarticle} %Comment to produce a presentation

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for logo

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{} % use the frame name

\begin{document}
    
    \author{The author name}
    \title{F1 Beamer template}
    \logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
%   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % hide navigation symbols

    \begin{frame}[plain] % cover F1
        \maketitle
        \newpage % works only in  article mode
    \end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{F2 Overview} % Table of contents slide
    \tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
    \newpage % works only in  article mode
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1} 

\begin{frame}{F3 in Section 1}
    \bigskip% for article mode
    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
    practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
    in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
    used as a canon for our understanding.
    
\end{frame} 

\subsection{Description}

\begin{frame}{F4 Connections}
    \centering
    \bigskip% for article mode
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={circle,fill, inner sep=1.5pt, outer sep=0pt},
    every label/.style={inner sep=0pt}] 
    \newdimen\R \R=1cm  
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in { 1,2,3,4,5,6}
    {\node (n\j) [dot, label=60*\j:$\i$] at (60*\j:\R) {};
        \draw[blue,thick]  (0,0) -- (n\j);
    }   
    {\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}
        \foreach \j in {\i,...,6}
        \draw (n\i) -- (n\j);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}

\mode<presentation>{ % % Only shown in presentation,
\begin{frame}{F5 in Section 2}  
    Shown only in mode presentation.
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{frame}{F6 in Section 2}  
    \bigskip % for article mode
     As I have shown elsewhere, Aristotle tells
    us that the objects in space and time, in the full sense of these
    terms, would be falsified.  
\end{frame}     

\end{document}
```