# Problem using `\addcontentsline` inside `\addtobeamertemplate` or `\newcommand`

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm trying to get a frame list containing frames that I select adding `\frameintoc` after frame environment begin. I Used [List of frames with beamer][Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer). My MWE is here:

```
\makeatletter%
\let\@starttocorig\@starttoc
\makeatother%%
\documentclass[fleqn,calc,xcolor={usenames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{calc,bookmark}
\definecolor{todo}{rgb}{0.75, 0.0, 0.2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother
%%% COUNTERS
\newcounter{todokey}%
\newcommand\todo[2][todo-\thetodokey]{%todo
    \addtocounter{todokey}{1}
    \noindent{%
        \color{todo}{#2}%
    }%
    \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is not used
    \linkdest{#1}%
   \addcontentsline{todo-\thepart}{subsubsection}{\textbullet\protect\hyperlink{#1}{#2}\hspace{1mm}}%
    %\addcontentsline{todo-\thepart}{subsubsection}{todo}
}
 \makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoftodosbasic}{%listoftodos
    \@starttocorig{todo-\thepart}
}
\newcommand\listtodosname{TODO}%listoftodo
\newcommand\listoftodos{%
\listtodosname\phantomsection: 

\listoftodosbasic}

%%frameintoc
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframesbasic{\@starttoc{cherryframes}}%%frameintoc cherrry
\makeatother
\newcommand\listofframesname{Important frames}
\newcommand\listofframes{\listofframesname: \listofframesbasic}
\newcommand\frameintoc{%
    \def\boolframeintoc{1}
%\phantomsection\linkdest{frametarget-\insertframenumber}%
%\addcontentsline{section}{makebox[2em][l]{hyperlink{frametarget-insertframenumber}{insertframenumber}hfill}hyperlink{frametarget-insertframenumber}{insertframetitle}par}%
}%
\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \mode<presentation>{%
        \only<1>{%
            \hypertarget{\insertframetitle}{}%
            %\ifx\beamer@shortframetitle\beamer@frametitle
                %\ifx\boolframeintoc1%
                    %frametitle - prioritate 3
                    %\addcontentsline{cherryframes}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{\scriptsize\insertframenumber\hfill}\insertframetitle\par}%
            %\fi
        }%
    }%
\def\boolframeintoc{0}
}
\makeatother 
\title{problem setting length block?}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{list of todo}
    \listoftodos
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{list of frames}
    \listofframes
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{one frame}\frameintoc
    \begin{block}{block 1}
check

this\todo{ad}, sjdsndns\todo{cawwo}


frame: \todo{889665}

\begin{align}
    &a+rt+6+44\label{oh}\\
    &r=0
\end{align}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{two frame}\frameintoc
    \begin{block}{block 1}
check

this\todo{ad}, sjdsndns\todo{cawwo}


frame: \todo{889665}

\begin{align}
    &a+rt+6+44\label{oh}\\
    &r=0
\end{align}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get an error for `\only<1>`: `Argument of \beamer@@@only has an extra }`; and one error for `\addcontentsline`: `Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete`.
I've also tried to not use `\addtobeamertemplate` but can't make addcontentsline working when used inside `\newcommand`.
Any suggestions?
Thankyou for attention and best regards.

**Update**

Running the code in the answer of [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer) result in the error: `Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete. error| Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`; while same code compile without error on overleaf using TeXLive 2021. I'm running pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian).

**Update two**

Part of the problem seems related to use of `allowframebreaks` that causes the difference between first and second line in the toc file `output.cherryframes`:

```
\contentsline {section}{\makebox [1em][l]{\normalsize 4\hfill }\normalsize {one frame\relax {} \let \reserved@d = *\def \par }\par } 
\contentsline {section}{\makebox [1em][l]{\normalsize 5\hfill }\normalsize {two frame}\par
```

where the frame titled "one frame" has the argument `allowframebreaks`. I'll try the makerobust pkg.
There could be problems related also to `\ifx` usage.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there were two problems:

1. use of `allowframebreaks` for frame to be added in the list of frames
2. Automatically Reset `\boolframeintoc` to zero after being set to one by `\frameintoc`do not work

In the code below the first problem is solved using package `makerobust`, the second using the approach of [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer) (ie `\newif`):

```
\makeatletter%
\let\@starttocorig\@starttoc
\makeatother%%
\documentclass[fleqn,calc,xcolor={usenames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{calc,bookmark,trace}
\definecolor{todo}{rgb}{0.75, 0.0, 0.2}
\usepackage{makerobust}
\MakeRobustCommand\usebeamertemplate
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother
%%% COUNTERS
\newcounter{todokey}%
\newcommand\todo[2][todo-\thetodokey]{%todo
\addtocounter{todokey}{1}
\noindent{%
    \color{todo}{#2}%
}%
\phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is not used
\linkdest{#1}%
\addcontentsline{todo-\thepart}{subsubsection}{\textbullet\protect\hyperlink{#1}{#2}\hspace{1mm}}%
%\addcontentsline{todo-\thepart}{subsubsection}{ todo}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoftodosbasic}{%listoftodos
\@starttocorig{todo-\thepart}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\listtodosname{TODO}%listoftodo
\newcommand\listoftodos{%
\listtodosname\phantomsection: 
\listoftodosbasic}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttocorig{cherryframes}}
\makeatother
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%\protect\insertframenumber:
\ifframeinlbf
\mode<presentation>{%
\only<1>{%
\hypertarget{\protect\insertframetitle}{}%
\addcontentsline{cherryframes}{section}{%
\protect\makebox[1em][l]{\normalsize\insertframenumber\hfill}\normalsize\insertframetitle%}%
}%
}%
\else\fi}%
{}%
\title{problem setting length block?}
\begin{document}
\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{list of todo}
\listoftodos
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,fragile]{list of frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}[fragile]{one frame}
\begin{block}{block 1}
check
this\todo{ad}, sjdsndns\todo{cawwo}
frame: \todo{889665}
\begin{align}
&a+rt+6+44\label{oh}\\
&r=0
\end{align}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}[fragile,allowframebreaks]{two frame}
\begin{block}{block 1}
check
this\todo{ad}, sjdsndns\todo{cawwo}
frame: \todo{889665}
\begin{align}
&a+rt+6+44\label{oh}\\
&r=0
\end{align}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```